Unable to capture query user output via PowerShell script via Task scheduler as SYSTEM context
I am trying to execute the below PowerShell script as a scheduler job as SYSTEM context on Windows machine.
$AllSessions = C:\WINDOWS\system32\query.exe user 2>&1
$UserSessions = $AllSessions | Select-String -Pattern '^>(?!Testuser1)(\w+)'
$UserSessions | Out-File "D:\output.txt"

While I execute this script locally, I get the result as below in the output file,
>Domain_user              console             1  Active      none   10/3/2024 11:47 AM

While I execute this as part of scheduler task job, the output file does not capture anything.
Can someone please suggest why I am unable to capture the output and how can I achieve this?

It works as system using psexec -sid powershell.  There must be some other problem running the script.

This probably means that your computer (local SYSTEM) account doesn't access to that information. To properly troubleshoot this, see: Scheduled Task Powershell Script - Runs OK as user account, but not as SYSTEM

As an aside, why do you use the (external) query.exe command for this? What do you try to achieve here? If it is retrieving the current user nanme, see; How do I get the current username in Windows PowerShell?.

I believe this is by design and changing the behavior has security risks. System runs as session 0 and does not have access to enumerate user based sessions. Have you tried seeing if you can enumerate Win32_LogonSession, Win32_LoggedOnUser running under this context? These two classes have the information you are looking for. Additionally qwinsta.exe is able to enumerate this information remotely. There is also sysinternals PsLoggedOn.exe. Also you can audit this through Event IDs 4624 (logon) and 4634 (logoff) from Security event logs.

@albvar: query.exe user (quser.exe) works just fine when run in the context of the SYSTEM account (as does query.exe session (qwinsta.exe); the only problem here is that the regex looks for character > at the start of the line, which by definition won't be there when running in the services session, such as from a scheduled task configured to run as SYSTEM (or any other account, as long as Run whether user is logged on or not is checked).

You can use pinvoke in power she'll to query the same information qwinsta exposes. Did it a few years ago.


tl;dr

It looks like you're looking for the currently interactively logged-on user(s) and associated session information, via the output from query.exe user (or, equivalently, quser.exe)

For the reasons explained in the next section, you can not find the relevant output line by looking for > as the first character when running from a scheduled task that runs whether or not a user is currently logged on (often, but not necessarily with the built-in
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user account).


Instead, look for substring Active:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\query.exe user |
  Select-String ' Active ' |
  Out-File "D:\output.txt"

Important:

query.exe's output is localized, so the above assumes that the Windows display language is English; adjust accordingly for other languages.

When running under the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM account, you can see what display language is in effect for it by executing intl.cpl, activating tab Administrative, and clicking on Copy settings..., list section Welcome screen, assuming you are an administrator; you may also modify that language setting there, namely by copying your settings.


Note:

Presumably, on a Windows server there can be multiple sessions Active simultaneously, via RDP, so the above may match multiple users / lines.

If you want to exclude a specific user such as Testuser1, the simplest approach is to append another Select-String call with -NotMatch:
 C:\WINDOWS\system32\query.exe user |
   Select-String ' Active ' |
   Select-String -NotMatch '^[> ]Testuser1' |
   Out-File "D:\output.txt"


Note that the regex, ^[> ]Testuser1, is formulated to work both with interactive invocation and invocation via the SYSTEM account.




Background information:
The > at the start of one of the lines output by query.exe user (or, equivalently, quser.exe) indicates the caller's session.
When query user is run:

in the by design invisible, non-interactive services session, such as from a scheduled task that runs with the option Run whether user is logged on or not as shown in the Task Scheduler GUI (taskschd.msc), or when run via psexec with the -s option (which runs as NT AUTHORITY\System)

there is no line that starts with >, because the services session isn't listed by query user, which lists interactive user sessions only (a line for services does show in the output of query session / qwinsta.exe, however).



This helped a lot and fixed my problem. Thanks mklement0 for the details and suggestion.
